# Is it possible to determine parallelism of tasks by using Task.Delay to force a new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, task-parallel-library

I am trying to determine that Tasks CAN run in parallel depending on decisions made by the task scheduler. I have been told this does not prove the case:

```
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        // should be 50000 without any parallelism
        var elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds; // on my machine actual result is around 10000
```

So I am very confused about this now. How could it be possible that the final result in executing time is less than the time it takes to perform each task * the amount of tasks and not prove some degree of parallelism?

Comment: You are running all Tasks in parallel (in theory at least). So totally it could be 1000 + a little overhead. If you `await` each task in the loop, then time would be around 1000*50.

Comment: You are making the incorrect assumption that awaiting a `Task.Delay` requires a concurrent thread. It could be theoretically a single thread that starts all delays in series, and then gets reactivated when the first delay stops and then finalizes each async method. It ultimately *is* executing on multiple threads (that’s what the thread pool is for after all) but it wouldn’t need to do that just by the result of 1000+x ms total execution duration.

Comment: @poke so considering that a new Task can in theory start a new thread - would that make use of logical cores? So what I mean is can Task.whenall be parallel or only concurrent?

Comment: Those would be normal threads, so you would be able to run more threads in parallel with more cores, if that’s what you mean. `Task.WhenAll` doesn’t actually care how or when the tasks are run or completed. I’m not entirely sure what you are asking.

Comment: @poke what I mean is that I have been told that all threads spawned by tasks from a request thread can only execute on the same logical core, meaning they can only timeswitch process and therefore cannot be parallel, only concurrent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to determine that Tasks CAN run in parallel depending on decisions made by the task scheduler... How could it be possible that the final result in executing time is less than the time it takes to perform each task * the amount of tasks and not prove some degree of parallelism?

It proves concurrency, which may be asynchronous concurrency or it may be parallelism. In this case, your code is doing asynchronous concurrency.

It's important to note that task schedulers only apply to *running* tasks - i.e., tasks that are actually executing code or are blocked. The thread that runs `await Task.Delay` neither executes code nor is blocked during the delay time.

> So what I mean is can Task.whenall be parallel or only concurrent?

You could - in theory - make use of `WhenAll` in a parallel fashion. You just need to change your code to be blocking instead of asynchronous, and it will run in parallel:

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
  tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
stopwatch.Stop();
var elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

In this case, your code is parallel. Using `Task.WhenAll` like this will work, but it is unusual. Normally, parallel code is consumed using blocking methods like `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: 'It's important to note that task schedulers only apply to running tasks - i.e., tasks that are actually executing code or are blocked. The thread that runs await Task.Delay neither executes code nor is blocked during the delay time.'

So this means that the cpu cannot move on and attempt any more work until this delay is finished right? And that proves parallel execution because the result is still less than 50000

Comment: The thread is available for other work while the delay is being awaited, so it (and the CPU) can work on other things. But of course, code that would be after the delay will not execute until the delay is completed at which point a thread will continue from there.

Comment: @poke sorry - I am confused again. So this answer does not prove parallel execution?

Comment: As Stephen said, awaiting the delays is *asynchronous concurrency* because the threads will not block for the duration of the delays. If you wanted parallelism, with parallel threads executing (or actively waiting), then you would have to block those threads using `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: It is debatable if having multiple threads blocked with `Thread.Sleep` constitutes parallelism. My understanding is that parallelism means having multiple cores/processors working at the same time. Which makes parallelism impossible in an single core machine.

Comment: I think my understanding now is that thread.sleep blocks the executing worker thread - yes - but that just means that the cpu will keep doing context switching between processes and the threads therein. the code in this answer will block at most 50 worker threads. So why would that ensure parallelism? This could still be done in a single core only by just timeswitching between the blocked threads I think.

Comment: @Craig: If you define "parallelism" to mean "multiple threads", then the code in my answer will suffice. If you define "parallelism" to mean "multiple cores", then replace `Thread.Sleep` with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to control the degree of parallelism yourself.

A better method than creating and starting the threads explicitly, is to use parallel for:

```
Parallel.For(0, 50, i => { Thread.Sleep(1000); } );
```

The Task Parallel mechanism then automatically determines the optimum number of threads (based on the number of available cores) and distributes the tasks among those threads.

This also reduces the overhead of creating more threads than can be executed in parallel.

Comment: Why is the await strange? You definitely have to await the delay for it to matter. Otherwise, execution will just continue with what comes after the `Task.Delay` call immediately, assuming that there is something, defeating its purpose.